# how to change file permission of a file permanently that is set back to default on boot

Tags: permissions, apache2, logrotate

I have a file `/var/logs/apache2/error.log`. And every time I boot, Its file permission is changed to default (unwritable) by the system. So, i have to run `chmod` command every time i boot-up. How to change it's file permission permanently.

Comment: Question - why? What is it you are trying to do that requires write access? Normal logging processes are generally recommended.

Comment: @RoryAlsop  to debug ajax, i need to check into error.log. And this is so full of logs. I normally delete it, and look for changes. But due to it's permission, is not editable.

Comment: @explorex - good range of tools allow you to manage logs without deleting. I always use a combination of grep and tail, which makes life very easy.

Comment: @RoryAlsop is `grep` and `tail` programs or soft packages?

Comment: @explorex - both part of unix/linux. Tail lets you look at the last lines of a file (http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tail) and grep lets you search through a file for instances you want to find (http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep). Well worth understanding the power of grep - invaluable!

Comment: @RoyAlsop thank you, your information is invaluable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the discussion in comments, for the purpose the OP is trying to achieve (looking at a simple subset of logs for a specific purpose), this may be an appropriate alternative solution:

[Tail](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tail) will let you look at the last lines of a file

[Grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) lets you search through a file for instances you want to find

Both are available as part of Unix/Linux and should be part of your essential toolkit.

Answer (score 5):

Log files are usually created by logrotate. The apache logfiles definition is stored on /etc/logrotate.d/apache2

The file looks like this in one of my servers:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        weekly
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if [ -f "`. /etc/apache2/envvars ; echo ${APACHE_PID_FILE:-/var/run/apache2.pid}`" ]; then
                        /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
                fi
        endscript
}
```

If you look at the create option, the values after the keyword are the permissions, user and group. Just edit your file and change this values.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing `anacron` is running `logrotate` at boot time.

If so, try editing the configuration file `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2`, and change

```
create 640 root adm
```

to whatever you prefer, e.g.

```
create 666 root adm
```

But other than the `apache2` service, what else needs to write to this file?

If this is on a server, it's probably a bad idea to make the file world writable.  For example, if somebody breaks in to your system, they can remove the log entries that would help you find the problem.

If you want read access, it might be better to add yourself to the `adm` group, e.g.

```
gpasswd -a `whoami` adm
```

This would also help if you really do need write access, e.g.

```
create 660 root adm
```

would be sufficient.

Comment: The usual reason is letting some customers or some software (traffic analysis, monitoring) access to the logs without granting it extra privileges that could be a security risk.

Comment: Read access, probably OK.  But the poster said write access was required too.

Comment: Ouch, now I'm wondering too...